# If, for any $w \in L$, there is a polynomial $P_w$ such that $f(z + w) = f(z) + P_w(z)$ then $f$ is a polynomial.

Tags: complex-analysis, periodic-functions

Let $f$ be an entire function and $L$ a lattice in $\Bbb C$. If, for any $w \in  L$, there is a polynomial $P_w$ such that
$f(z + w) = f(z) + P_w(z)$
then $f$ is a polynomial.

If I can show that the degree of $\{p_w(z)| w \in L\}$ has a bound say $k \in \Bbb N$ then for any $z \in \Bbb C$ $\exists z_0 \in L_0$ where $L_0$ is the fundamental lattice such that $f(z)=f(z_0)+p_w(z)$ then  $|f(z)| < c|z|^k$ for large $z \in \Bbb C$. Then by First Liouville Theorem $f$ would be a constant.

Now the problem is **how to show "the degree of $\{p_w(z)| w \in L\}$ has a bound"**.

Comment: Let $\omega_1,\,\omega_2$ be a basis of the lattice. What relation is there between $P_{k\omega_1 + n\omega_2}$ and $P_{\omega_1},\, P_{\omega_2}$?

Comment: Excellent. Thanks

Comment: I hope you don't believe $P_{k\omega_1 + n\omega_2} = k P_{\omega_1} + n P_{\omega_2}$. _That_ only holds in trivial cases.

Comment: I know this is not true. The actual result is sum of $p_w $ where the variable changes. ;). Just wanted to keep secret for the people who will see this question later. Only I can say that the degree will be fixed 

Comment: Good. Just wanted to make sure you didn't believe something too-good-to-be-true. Although, to be honest, more than half of complex analysis is too-good-to-be-true ;)

Comment: Right indeed thats why it has a relevant connection with many significant branches in math.